How to sort some TypeScript AST nodes and print the output as a TypeScript file?
I have this code, which I would like to sort the link(foo) value by the string text:
import Text from '~/text.js'

export default function rule(text: Text) {
  text.rule('*-able').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'able' })
  text.rule('*-ably').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ably' })
  // Matches suffix "-al"
  text.rule('*-al').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'al' })
  // Matches suffix "-dom"
  text.rule('*-dom').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'dom' })
  // Matches suffix "-esque"
  text.rule('*-esque').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'esque' })
  // Matches -ful on words.
  text
    .rule('*-ful')
    .seek({ base: true })
    .seek({ make: 'ful', flow: 'full' })
  // Matches suffix "-hood"
  text.rule('*-hood').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'hood' })
  // Matches suffix "-ish"
  text.rule('*-ish').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ish' })
  // Matches suffix "-ism"
  text.rule('*-ism').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ism' })
  // Matches suffix "-ist"
  text.rule('*-ist').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ist' })
  // Matches suffix "-ity"
  text.rule('*-ity').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ity' })
  // Matches suffix "-ization"
  text.rule('*-ization').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ization' })
  // Matches suffix "-ize"
  text.rule('*-ize').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ize' })
  // Matches -ly on words.
  text.rule('*-ly').seek({ base: true }).seek({ make: 'ly' })
  text.rule('*-ness').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ness' })
  // Matches -ious on y-ending words.
  text
    .rule('*-y-ious')
    .seek({ base: true })
    .seek({ tail: true, read: 'y', hide: true, make: 'ious' })
  // Matches prefix "anti-"
  text.rule('anti-*').seek({ read: 'anti' }).seek({ rest: true })
  // Matches prefix "auto-"
  text.rule('auto-*').seek({ read: 'auto' }).seek({ rest: true })
  // Matches prefix "co-"
  text.rule('co-*').seek({ read: 'co' }).seek({ rest: true })
  // Plugs in the main word into a maker for a word.
  text.rule('self').seek({ self: true })
  text.rule('un-*').seek({ read: 'un' }).seek({ rest: true })
  // Matches -iful on y-ending words.
  text
    .rule('*-y-iful')
    .seek({ base: true })
    .seek({ tail: true, read: 'y', hide: true, make: 'i' })
    .seek({ make: 'ful', flow: 'full' })
    .make('*-ly')
  // Matches plural on y-ending words
  text
    .rule('*-y-plural')
    .seek({ base: true })
    .seek({ tail: true, read: 'y', hide: true, make: 'ies' })
    .bind('plurality', 'plural')
  // Matches plural on non-y-ending words
  text
    .rule('*-plural')
    .seek({ base: true })
    .seek({ tail: true, void: 'y', make: 's' })
    .bind('plurality', 'plural')
  // Matches suffix "-ary"
  text.rule('*-ary').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ary' })
  // Matches suffix "-ate"
  text.rule('*-ate').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ate' })
  // Matches suffix "-en"
  text.rule('*-en').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'en' })
  // Matches suffix "-ify"
  text.rule('*-ify').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ify' })
  // Matches suffix "-ine"
  text.rule('*-ine').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ine' })
  // Matches suffix "-ive"
  text.rule('*-ive').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ive' })
  // Matches suffix "-less"
  text.rule('*-less').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'less' })
  // Matches suffix "-like"
  text.rule('*-like').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'like' })
  // Matches suffix "-ment"
  text.rule('*-ment').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ment' })
  // Matches suffix "-most"
  text.rule('*-most').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'most' })
  // Matches suffix "-ory"
  text.rule('*-ory').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ory' })
  // Matches suffix "-ous"
  text.rule('*-ous').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ous' })
  // Matches suffix "-ship"
  text.rule('*-ship').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ship' })
  // Matches suffix "-ship"
  text.rule('*-ship').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ship' })
  // Matches suffix "-some"
  text.rule('*-some').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'some' })
  // Matches suffix "-ward"
  text.rule('*-ward').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ward' })
  // Matches suffix "-wise"
  text.rule('*-wise').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'wise' })
  // Matches prefix "ante-"
  text.rule('ante-*').seek({ read: 'ante' }).seek({ rest: true })
  // Matches prefix "bi-"
  text.rule('bi-*').seek({ read: 'bi' }).seek({ rest: true })
  // Matches prefix "circum-"
  text.rule('circum-*').seek({ read: 'circum' }).seek({ rest: true })
  // Matches prefix "counter-"
  text.rule('counter-*').seek({ read: 'counter' }).seek({ rest: true })
  // Matches prefix "de-"
  text.rule('de-*').seek({ read: 'de' }).seek({ rest: true })
  // Matches prefix "dis-"
  text.rule('dis-*').seek({ read: 'dis' }).seek({ rest: true })
  // Matches prefix "epi-"
  text.rule('epi-*').seek({ read: 'epi' }).seek({ rest: true })
  // Matches prefix "extra-"
  text.rule('extra-*').seek({ read: 'extra' }).seek({ rest: true })
  // Matches prefix "hyper-"
  text.rule('hyper-*').seek({ read: 'hyper' }).seek({ rest: true })
  // Matches prefix "in-"
  text.rule('in-*').seek({ read: 'in' }).seek({ rest: true })
  // Matches prefix "infra-"
  text.rule('infra-*').seek({ read: 'infra' }).seek({ rest: true })
  // Matches prefix "inter-"
  text.rule('inter-*').seek({ read: 'inter' }).seek({ rest: true })
  // Matches prefix "micro-"
  text.rule('micro-*').seek({ read: 'micro' }).seek({ rest: true })
  // Matches prefix "mis-"
  text.rule('mis-*').seek({ read: 'mis' }).seek({ rest: true })
  // Matches prefix "multi-"
  text.rule('multi-*').seek({ read: 'multi' }).seek({ rest: true })
  // Matches prefix "neo-"
  text.rule('neo-*').seek({ read: 'neo' }).seek({ rest: true })
  // Matches prefix "non-"
  text.rule('non-*').seek({ read: 'non' }).seek({ rest: true })
  // Matches prefix "over-"
  text.rule('over-*').seek({ read: 'over' }).seek({ rest: true })
  // Matches prefix "post-"
  text.rule('post-*').seek({ read: 'post' }).seek({ rest: true })
  // Matches prefix "pre-"
  text.rule('pre-*').seek({ read: 'pre' }).seek({ rest: true })
  // Matches prefix "quasi-"
  text.rule('quasi-*').seek({ read: 'quasi' }).seek({ rest: true })
  // Matches prefix "re-"
  text.rule('re-*').seek({ read: 're' }).seek({ rest: true })
  // Matches prefix "semi-"
  text.rule('semi-*').seek({ read: 'semi' }).seek({ rest: true })
  // Matches prefix "sub-"
  text.rule('sub-*').seek({ read: 'sub' }).seek({ rest: true })
  // Matches prefix "super-"
  text.rule('super-*').seek({ read: 'super' }).seek({ rest: true })
  // Matches prefix "trans-"
  text.rule('trans-*').seek({ read: 'trans' }).seek({ rest: true })
  // Matches prefix "tri-"
  text.rule('tri-*').seek({ read: 'tri' }).seek({ rest: true })
  // Matches prefix "ultra-"
  text.rule('ultra-*').seek({ read: 'ultra' }).seek({ rest: true })
  // Matches prefix "ultra-"
  text.rule('ultra-*').seek({ read: 'ultra' }).seek({ rest: true })
  // Matches prefix "under-"
  text.rule('under-*').seek({ read: 'under' }).seek({ rest: true })
}

So it should be sorted so the string inside text.link(string) is in alphabetical order, copying over the DSL chunks related to that. It mostly did, but notice this is not sorted correctly:
text
  .rule('*-y-ious')
  .seek({ base: true })
  .seek({ tail: true, read: 'y', hide: true, make: 'ious' })
// Matches prefix "anti-"
text.rule('anti-*').seek({ read: 'anti' }).seek({ rest: true })
// Matches prefix "auto-"
text.rule('auto-*').seek({ read: 'auto' }).seek({ rest: true })
// Matches prefix "co-"
text.rule('co-*').seek({ read: 'co' }).seek({ rest: true })
// Plugs in the main word into a maker for a word.
text.rule('self').seek({ self: true })
text.rule('un-*').seek({ read: 'un' }).seek({ rest: true })
// Matches -iful on y-ending words.
text
  .rule('*-y-iful')
  .seek({ base: true })
  .seek({ tail: true, read: 'y', hide: true, make: 'i' })
  .seek({ make: 'ful', flow: 'full' })
  .make('*-ly')
// Matches plural on y-ending words
text
  .rule('*-y-plural')
  .seek({ base: true })
  .seek({ tail: true, read: 'y', hide: true, make: 'ies' })
  .bind('plurality', 'plural')
// Matches plural on non-y-ending words
text
  .rule('*-plural')
  .seek({ base: true })
  .seek({ tail: true, void: 'y', make: 's' })
  .bind('plurality', 'plural')
// Matches suffix "-ary"
text.rule('*-ary').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ary' })
// Matches suffix "-ate"
text.rule('*-ate').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ate' })

How do I accomplish this? I have spent the past few hours tinkering with the typescript parser/generator, and can somewhat print the AST as text, but it is not liking my sorting function...
import * as fs from 'fs'
import * as ts from 'typescript'

const file = String(process.argv[2])
// Create a Program to represent the project, then pull out the
// source file to parse its AST.
// let program = ts.createProgram([file], { allowJs: false })
// const sourceFile = program.getSourceFile(file)
const sourceFile = ts.createSourceFile(
  file,
  fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf-8'),
  ts.ScriptTarget.ESNext,
  true,
)

// To print the AST, we'll use TypeScript's printer
const printer = ts.createPrinter({
  newLine: ts.NewLineKind.LineFeed,
})

// To give constructive error messages, keep track of found and un-found identifiers
const unfoundNodes = [],
  foundNodes = []

// Loop through the root AST nodes of the file
if (sourceFile) {
  const text: Array<string> = []
  ts.forEachChild(sourceFile, node => {
    let name = ''

    if (
      ts.isFunctionDeclaration(node) &&
      node.name.escapedText === 'rule'
    ) {
      node.body.statements.sort((a, b) => {
        const x =
          a.expression.expression.expression.expression?.expression
            ?.arguments?.[0]?.text ||
          a.expression.expression.expression.expression?.arguments?.[0]
            ?.text ||
          a.expression.expression.expression.arguments?.[0]?.text
        const y =
          b.expression.expression.expression?.expression?.expression
            ?.arguments?.[0]?.text ||
          b.expression.expression.expression.expression?.arguments?.[0]
            ?.text ||
          b.expression.expression.expression.arguments?.[0]?.text

        if (x && y) {
          if (x < y) {
            return -1
          }
          if (x > y) {
            return 1
          }
          return 0
        }
        console.log(x, y, a.expression.arguments?.[0])
        return 1
      })
    }

    const nodeString = printer.printNode(
      ts.EmitHint.Unspecified,
      node,
      sourceFile,
    )
    text.push(nodeString)
  })

  fs.writeFileSync(file, text.join('\n'))
}

That typescript AST is different from the one here, for example. I am using typescript@5.4.4.
How do I get that sorting function to properly sort the input?
Ideally, if you know how to put spaces between each chunk/comment, that would be even better.

I tried to reproduce this and your code is throwing type a few type errors, by namely this one Property 'sort' does not exist on type 'NodeArray<Statement>'.(2339). It would seem that what you are trying to sort is not actually an instance of Array. I don't know what the answer here is at the moment, but I would give https://ts-morph.com/ a look. The API is much easier to understand and deal with.

@AlexWayne alright thanks for the suggestion on ts-morph, that helped me see the bug more clearly, and arrive at a solution. I appreciate it!

Thanks to @AlexWayne's suggestion of using ts-morph, I was able to get the right answer. It had to do with the weird EcmaScript AST structure, where more calls in the chain result in a deeper nested CallExpression, which is kind of backwards reasoning / counterintuitive. But I figured it out (even though ts-morph doesn't have the nicest console.log debugging of the AST types, it had a simple enough API):
import * as fs from 'fs'
import * as ts from 'typescript'
import pathResolver from 'path'
import {
  Node,
  StringLiteral,
  Project,
  SyntaxKind,
  CallExpression,
  Expression,
  ExpressionStatement,
  PropertyAccessExpression,
} from 'ts-morph'

const file = pathResolver.resolve(String(process.argv[2]))

const project = new Project({
  tsConfigFilePath: './tsconfig.json',
})

const sourceFile = project.addSourceFileAtPath(file) // or addSourceFileAtPathIfExists
const funcBody = sourceFile.getFunction('rule')?.getBody()
const children = funcBody
  ?.getChildAtIndexIfKind(1, SyntaxKind.SyntaxList)
  ?.getChildrenOfKind(SyntaxKind.ExpressionStatement)

children?.sort((a, b) => {
  const x = getFunctionLabel(a)
  const y = getFunctionLabel(b)
  console.log(x, y)
  return x.localeCompare(y)
})

children?.forEach((a, i) => {
  a.setOrder(i)
})

function getFunctionLabel(a: ExpressionStatement): string {
  let text: string | undefined
  let node:
    | CallExpression<ts.CallExpression>
    | PropertyAccessExpression<ts.PropertyAccessExpression>
    | ExpressionStatement
    | undefined = a
  while (node) {
    node = node?.getChildAtIndexIfKind(0, SyntaxKind.CallExpression)
    const child = node?.getChildAtIndexIfKind(
      0,
      SyntaxKind.PropertyAccessExpression,
    )
    const isLeaf = Boolean(
      child?.getChildAtIndexIfKind(0, SyntaxKind.Identifier),
    )

    if (isLeaf) {
      const arg = node?.getArguments()?.[0]
      if (arg instanceof StringLiteral) {
        text = arg.getLiteralValue()
        break
      }
    }

    node = child
  }
  return text
}

sourceFile.saveSync()

First, get the function ExpressionStatement nodes (the function body), then get the function "label" for them (the 1st string literal arg), then sort by that, and finally setOrder to reorder. Then save.
I just removed the comments for now, they can be programmatically added back at some point. But here is the final output:
import Text from '~/text.js'

export default function rule(text: Text) {
  text.rule('*-able').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'able' })
  text.rule('*-ably').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ably' })
  text.rule('*-al').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'al' })
  text.rule('*-ary').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ary' })
  text.rule('*-ate').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ate' })
  text.rule('*-dom').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'dom' })
  text.rule('*-en').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'en' })
  text.rule('*-esque').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'esque' })
  text
    .rule('*-ful')
    .seek({ base: true })
    .seek({ make: 'ful', flow: 'full' })
  text.rule('*-hood').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'hood' })
  text.rule('*-ify').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ify' })
  text.rule('*-ine').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ine' })
  text.rule('*-ish').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ish' })
  text.rule('*-ism').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ism' })
  text.rule('*-ist').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ist' })
  text.rule('*-ity').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ity' })
  text.rule('*-ive').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ive' })
  text.rule('*-ization').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ization' })
  text.rule('*-ize').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ize' })
  text.rule('*-less').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'less' })
  text.rule('*-like').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'like' })
  text.rule('*-ly').seek({ base: true }).seek({ make: 'ly' })
  text.rule('*-ment').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ment' })
  text.rule('*-most').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'most' })
  text.rule('*-ness').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ness' })
  text.rule('*-ory').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ory' })
  text.rule('*-ous').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ous' })
  text
    .rule('*-plural')
    .seek({ base: true })
    .seek({ tail: true, void: 'y', make: 's' })
    .bind('plurality', 'plural')
  text.rule('*-ship').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ship' })
  text.rule('*-ship').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ship' })
  text.rule('*-some').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'some' })
  text.rule('*-ward').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'ward' })
  text.rule('*-wise').seek({ base: true }).seek({ read: 'wise' })
  text
    .rule('*-y-iful')
    .seek({ base: true })
    .seek({ tail: true, read: 'y', hide: true, make: 'i' })
    .seek({ make: 'ful', flow: 'full' })
    .make('*-ly')
  text
    .rule('*-y-ious')
    .seek({ base: true })
    .seek({ tail: true, read: 'y', hide: true, make: 'ious' })
  text
    .rule('*-y-plural')
    .seek({ base: true })
    .seek({ tail: true, read: 'y', hide: true, make: 'ies' })
    .bind('plurality', 'plural')
  text.rule('ante-*').seek({ read: 'ante' }).seek({ rest: true })
  text.rule('anti-*').seek({ read: 'anti' }).seek({ rest: true })
  text.rule('auto-*').seek({ read: 'auto' }).seek({ rest: true })
  text.rule('bi-*').seek({ read: 'bi' }).seek({ rest: true })
  text.rule('circum-*').seek({ read: 'circum' }).seek({ rest: true })
  text.rule('co-*').seek({ read: 'co' }).seek({ rest: true })
  text.rule('counter-*').seek({ read: 'counter' }).seek({ rest: true })
  text.rule('de-*').seek({ read: 'de' }).seek({ rest: true })
  text.rule('dis-*').seek({ read: 'dis' }).seek({ rest: true })
  text.rule('epi-*').seek({ read: 'epi' }).seek({ rest: true })
  text.rule('extra-*').seek({ read: 'extra' }).seek({ rest: true })
  text.rule('hyper-*').seek({ read: 'hyper' }).seek({ rest: true })
  text.rule('in-*').seek({ read: 'in' }).seek({ rest: true })
  text.rule('infra-*').seek({ read: 'infra' }).seek({ rest: true })
  text.rule('inter-*').seek({ read: 'inter' }).seek({ rest: true })
  text.rule('micro-*').seek({ read: 'micro' }).seek({ rest: true })
  text.rule('mis-*').seek({ read: 'mis' }).seek({ rest: true })
  text.rule('multi-*').seek({ read: 'multi' }).seek({ rest: true })
  text.rule('neo-*').seek({ read: 'neo' }).seek({ rest: true })
  text.rule('non-*').seek({ read: 'non' }).seek({ rest: true })
  text.rule('over-*').seek({ read: 'over' }).seek({ rest: true })
  text.rule('post-*').seek({ read: 'post' }).seek({ rest: true })
  text.rule('pre-*').seek({ read: 'pre' }).seek({ rest: true })
  text.rule('quasi-*').seek({ read: 'quasi' }).seek({ rest: true })
  text.rule('re-*').seek({ read: 're' }).seek({ rest: true })
  text.rule('self').seek({ self: true })
  text.rule('semi-*').seek({ read: 'semi' }).seek({ rest: true })
  text.rule('sub-*').seek({ read: 'sub' }).seek({ rest: true })
  text.rule('super-*').seek({ read: 'super' }).seek({ rest: true })
  text.rule('trans-*').seek({ read: 'trans' }).seek({ rest: true })
  text.rule('tri-*').seek({ read: 'tri' }).seek({ rest: true })
  text.rule('ultra-*').seek({ read: 'ultra' }).seek({ rest: true })
  text.rule('un-*').seek({ read: 'un' }).seek({ rest: true })
  text.rule('under-*').seek({ read: 'under' }).seek({ rest: true })
}

